# Define an List field without referencing a specific type parameter

Tags: java, generics

How can I define a List field as follows without referencing a specific type parameter:

```
private final List<? extends A<B, ?[0] extends C, ?[1] extends D<B, ?[0]>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where:

- A is an abstract class;
- B is a generic type defined in the class;
- C is an abstract class;
- D is an abstract class.

Comment: I didn't down voted your question. However, it seems to me that you MUST understand some basic patterns...

Comment: what are you trying to refer to with the `?[0]`?

Comment: Hi Hawk, "?[0]" refers to the first unknown type (which extends C), "?[1]" to the second (which extends D). The problem is that D need the first unknown type as attribute but in Java I can't refer to an unknown type (I can only write "?").

Comment: @Alessandro next time please mention me in your comment at the beginning of your message like `@Hawk`, because I have **NOT** been notified of your reply and almost missed it.

You don't have to notify the Question/Answer author you are currently writing the comment to.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I was able to come up with was:

```
abstract class ClassA<B, C, F extends C, G extends ClassD<B, F>> {}

abstract class ClassC{}

class SubtypeC extends ClassC{}

abstract class ClassD<X, Y>{}

class SubtypeD extends ClassD<String, SubtypeC>{}

class Main{
    private final List<? extends A<String, ClassC, SubtypeC, SubtypeD>> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I am not aware of a possibility of defining a generic type with type parameters (something like `class ClassA<D<B, F>>` - the D here would need to be a class).